# Specific php and swift code for image uploading to sftp

Tags: php, swift

php script and xcode shows that here is

> ****** response data = 
>   **Notice**:  Undefined index: userId in **/home/raimonds/script.php** on line **36**
>   {"Message":"First name field empty","Status":"Error","userId":null}

so here is the php code :

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST["firstName"])){

    $firstName = isset($_POST["firstName"]) ? $_POST["firstName"] : "";
    $lastName = isset($_POST["lastName"]) ? $_POST["lastName"] : "";
    $userId = isset($_POST["userId"]) ? $_POST["userId"] : "";
    $target_dir = "uploads/";

    if(!file_exists($target_dir))
    {
    mkdir($target_dir, 0777, true);
    }

    $target_dir = $target_dir . "/" . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_dir)) {
        echo json_encode([
        "Message" => "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.",
        "Status" => "OK",
        "userId" => $_POST["userId"]
        ]);

    } else {
        echo json_encode([
        "Message" => "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.",
        "Status" => "Error",
        "userId" => $_POST["userId"]
        ]);
    }

}else{

        echo json_encode([
        "Message" => "First name field empty",
        "Status" => "Error",
        "userId" => $_POST["userId"]
        ]);

}

?>
```

can you please help me? xcode part was:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  ImageUploader
//
//  Created by Raimonds on 14/05/15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Raimonds. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
    UINavigationControllerDelegate

{
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var myActivityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func uploadButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        myImageUploadRequest()

    }

    @IBAction func selectPhotoButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {

        var myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        myPickerController.delegate = self;
        myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary

        self.presentViewController(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject])

    {

     myImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as?
        UIImage

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    }





    func myImageUploadRequest()

    {

        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://raimonds.gtd.lv/script.php");
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!);
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST";


        let param = [
            "firstName"  :  "firstName",
            "lastName"  :  "lastName",
            "userId"  :  "9"
        ]

        let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

        request.setValue("multipart/form-data: boundary=\(boundary)" , forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImageView.image, 1)

        if (imageData==nil) {return; }

        request.HTTPBody = createBodyWithParameters(param, filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: imageData, boundary: boundary)

        myActivityIndicator.startAnimating();

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                println("error=\(error)")
                return
            }


            println("******* response = \(response)")

            let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            println("****** response data = \(responseString!)")

            var err: NSError?
            var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers, error: &err)
              as? NSDictionary


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                self.myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.myImageView.image = nil;

            });


    }


    task.resume()


}


    func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData  {

        var body = NSMutableData();

        if parameters != nil {
            for (key, value) in parameters! {
                body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
                body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")

            }
        }

        let filename = "user-profile.jpg"

        let mimetype = "image/jpg"

        body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
        body.appendData(imageDataKey)
        body.appendString("\r\n")

        body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")

        return body
    }

    func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
        return "Boundary--\(NSUUID().UUIDString)"
    }

}

extension NSMutableData {
    func appendString(string: String) {
        let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
        appendData(data!)
    }




}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some problem in your swift code, because you don't send POST data into php

Try to look how send swift POST request:
http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/swift-how-to-send-a-post-request-to-a-php-script/

You need something like that:

```
var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://raimonds.gtd.lv/script.php")!
var request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
var bodyData = "firstName=firstName&lastName=lastName&userId=9"
request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
{
    (response, data, error) in
    println(response)

}
```

Comment: Can you please check it out? I will paste xcode code here.

Comment: still the same error. Can you please help me dude? :)

Comment: can you update your php and after <?php add `var_dump($_POST); die;` and update your question with this dump?